# 43 seconds to mount swap on /dev/mapper/cryptswap1

Tags: linux-mint, mount, partition, swap

My Linux Mint takes longer than I would expect it to boot.

Checking `dmesg` I see the following consecutive entries:

```
[    8.335668] Adding 9767484k swap on /dev/mapper/cryptswap1.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:9767484k SS
[   51.030010] EXT4-fs (sdc): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: user_xattr
```

I suspect the `Adding [...]` operation is taking a long time, from what I'm interpreting from this log.

"Should" this take so long to complete? Does this perhaps indicate an issue with mounting?

Comment: By the time you get the `Adding Xk swap on Y message`, it's already done... so whatever is slow happens afterwards. Do you have to enter a passphrase, does that happen before or after swap? (wait an extra minute before entering passphrase to find out)

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing out that it's something afterwards. No, I'm not asked for a passphrase while booting up. Linux Mint asks me for my username as usual at the login screen, which logs me in to the window manager.